# How to push elements into array based on dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object and I want to fill an array with the object property and repeat each property a number of times, based on its value. An example:

```
obj = {
   watches: 3
   rings: 1
}
// => ['watches', 'watches', 'watches', 'rings']
```

Below is what I have so far. I'm having a hard time figuring how to repeat each property based on the associated value?

```js
function arrayBuilder(obj) {
  let objToArr = [];

  for (let [property, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    objToArr.push(property);
  }
  return objToArr;
}

console.log(arrayBuilder({watches: 3, rings: 1}));
// => [ 'watches', 'rings' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You were just missing an inner loop:

```js
function arrayBuilder(obj) {
  let objToArr = [];

  for (let [property, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    for(var i=0; i<value; i++){
      objToArr.push(property);
    }
  }
  return objToArr;
}

console.log(arrayBuilder({watches: 3, rings: 1}));
```

Comment: Ah, gosh. So obvious in hindsight. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (note the support) with [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```js
const obj = {
   watches: 3,
   rings: 1
}

const result = Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => Array(v).fill(k));

console.log(result);
```

Or [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), if flatMap is not supported:

```js
const obj = {
   watches: 3,
   rings: 1
}

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => [...r, ...Array(v).fill(k)], []); // or r.concat(Array(v).fill(k)) instead of the spread

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't seen `Array.fill` before.

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `r.concat(Array(v).fill(k))` in the second example?

Comment: It's the same in this case, so not really.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another loop:

```
 for (let [property, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
   for(let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
     objToArr.push(property);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option using repeat and split methods

```js
var obj = {
   watches: 3,
   rings: 1
}
let result = []
for(key in obj){
  result.push(...key.concat(" ").repeat(obj[key]).trim().split(" "))
}

console.log(result)
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZVzoGB?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

Go through the keys, for each key, create an array of the required length, fill the resulting array with the names of the key, and [combine the resulting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/4989460):

```js
function arrayBuilder(obj) {
  return [].concat.apply(
    [],
    Object
      .entries(obj)
      .map(([key, value]) => new Array(value).fill(key))
  )
}
console.log(arrayBuilder({watches: 3, rings: 1}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const obj = { watches: 3, rings: 1 }

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => 
   [...acc, ...new Array(obj[key]).fill(key)], [])

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to get the keys from the object and use them to get the length of the array needed for the [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill). Using `Array.fill` you can fill the array with the same values once you have it setup with the correct length.